# try catch doesn't work correct T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to ask why (try catch) doesn't work correct because when is error in person 2 trigger showed problem. Don`t ask about different between table person and table person 2 this is only example to show problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Example
ON Person
after INSERT
AS

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO [Person2]
    SELECT 
        inserted.Name,
        inserted.Surname,
        inserted.Age,
        inserted.Street
    FROM   inserted
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Insert working correct if trigger is delated

```
INSERT INTO Person
Values
('Jhon', 'Kowalsky', '12', null)
```

error

> (0 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 3616, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 An error was raised during trigger
>   execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if
>   any, has been rolled back.

table Person - here you can see one difference between person and person 2 Street allow nulls

[image]

table Person 2 - here you can see one difference between person and person 2 Street doesn't allow nulls

[image]

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` is implicitly on inside triggers.

Comment: @Martin Smith Can you write this as answer? because now working correct. Thanks for helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Example 

    ON dbo.Person
    AFTER INSERT

AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @OwnTran BIT

    SET @OwnTran = 0

    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 
        BEGIN 
            SET @OwnTran = 1
            BEGIN TRAN
        END

    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO dbo.Person2 (Name, Surname, Age, Street)
        SELECT  
              i.Name 
            , i.Surname 
            , i.Age 
            , i.Street
        FROM INSERTED i

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @em NVARCHAR(MAX), @sev INT, @st INT

        SELECT  @em = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @sev = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @st = ERROR_STATE()

        RAISERROR(@em, @sev, @st)

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
            ROLLBACK TRAN

    END CATCH

    IF @OwnTran = 1 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN
    END

END
```